# List out the table content from a Shared Excel file by using API

Tags: excel, api, onedrive

I have an excel table and which is shared by my colleague. I want to retrieve the table data by using the Excel API.

What I did first, I have uploaded a sample excel file with a table content in my OneDrive Account (Business);
and executed the below API by using Microsoft Graph Explorer and got the result as expected.

API - 1: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/Employee_Details.xlsx:/workbook/tables/table1/columns

Response(expected)

```
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('4f26b2bb-0260-43f6-bf09-6d7bc68fc09b')/drive/root/workbook/tables('table1')/columns",
  "value": [
      {
          "@odata.id": "/users('4f26b2bb-0260-43f6-bf09-6d7bc68fc09b')/drive/root/workbook/tables(C4FE79CADFC5%7D%27)/columns(%271%27)",
          "values": [
              ["Name"],
              ["MS Virat"]
          ],
          "id": "1",
          "index": 0,
          "name": "Name"
      },
      {
          "@odata.id": "/users('4f26b2bb-0260-43f6-bf09-6d7bc68fc09b')/drive/root/workbook/tables(C4FE79CADFC5%7D%27)/columns(%272%27)",
          "values": [
              ["Status"],
              ["Batting"]
          ],
          "id": "2",
          "index": 1,
          "name": "Status"
      }
   ]
}
```

---

This below API can help to list out all the items Shared to me,
API - 2 
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/sharedWithMe

My question is, what modification I need to do in the below API URL to list out the column details of a Shared Excel Table.

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/sharedWithMe

Thank You,